# Mounting a cifs share dir_mode and file_mode are being ignored

Tags: permissions, mount, cifs, fstab

I have an Ubuntu Server that is trying to mount a Windows Server shared folder.

Firstly, what I'm trying to do here is mount the share as the person in the credentials file and all actions take place as this person regardless of what user on the Ubuntu server is accessing the files.

**`/etc/fstab`**

```
//server/data /media/data cifs credentials=/root/.credentials,iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlm,noexec,dir_mode=0770,file_mode=0660,rw 0 0
```

**`mount -l`**

```
//server/data on /media/data type cifs (rw,noexec,relatime,vers=1.0,sec=ntlm,cache=strict,username=windows_user,uid=0,noforceuid,gid=0,noforcegid,addr=192.168.50.31,file_mode=0755,dir_mode=0755,nounix,serverino,mapposix,rsize=61440,wsize=65536,echo_interval=60,actimeo=1)
```

I can read/write as the root user but I can only read as any other user on the Ubuntu server. How can I give other users (like my web server user) write access to this cifs share?

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

I was testing changes to `/etc/fstab` by just running `mount /media/data -o remount` to remount the share but I had to actually reboot for changes to take place.